# Partial recovery SQLServer transaction log

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I have database 1 and database 2 on SQLServer2014. Database 2 is a complete backup of database 2.

Every day I would like to restore on database 2 only a part of the transactions performed during the day on database 1 (for example I need all transactions from 8.00 to 12.00).

There is a way to identify all transactions made during that time and restore them on database 2?

Do you have any other suggestions for doing this?

Comment: You can restore a database to a particular point in time with transaction log backups and [`STOPAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_to_pit_using_STOPAT), but you cannot selectively apply only transactions from a certain time window, because transactional consistency could not be guaranteed this way. If you need that, you'll need to build your own tables that record the changes and their timestamps (or use a history table). Database transactions should not be confused with business transactions.

Comment: Database 1 contains hundreds of tables and unfortunately I do not have the opportunity to know the tables involved in the operations that I am interested in reporting on database 2. Can you suggest me another solution?

Comment: Is database 2 read-only? If not, there is no method to leverage the transaction log to apply changes. If it is read-only, you could periodically restore logs restore logs with the stopat and standby options to the desired piont in time (an offline operation). Log shipping, database mirroring, availability groups, and snapshots are also options.

Comment: You can spend $$$ on commercial solutions that promise to decode the transaction log for you -- I have no personal experience with any of them, and they don't come cheap. Overall, doing this with backups only is far more difficult than setting up something like [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) or replication.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes, database 2 is read-only

Comment: Given the reporting database is read-only, it seems any of the options I mentioned will fit your need.

Comment: @DanGuzman with your solution do I have to restore all the db or do I have the possibility to select the transactions from 8 to 12 and restore only those on database 2?

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved by  doing the partial backups
Please take a look at the below links it may help

https://sqlbak.com/blog/back-up-files-filegroups

Another helpful link on same note
https://sqlbak.com/academy/partial-backup